Describing the Eigenspace of a Linear Transformation on $\Bbb R^3$ that Rotates Points About a Line Through the Origin
Let A be the matrix of the linear transformation $T$. Without writing A, find an eigenvalue of A and describe the eigenspace in the following situations.
a. $T$ is the transformation on $\Bbb R^2$ that reflects points across some line through the origin.
b. $T$ is the transformation on $\Bbb R^3$ that rotates points about some line through the origin.
For part A I believe an eigenvalue would be 1, and the eigenspace would be the line through the origin. For part B I know that 1 is an eigenvalue (maybe the only one?) since the rotation preserves the length. I am confused about how to describe the eigenspace in this scenario. My initial thought is that the eigenspace is the line that points are rotated around but I think I am missing something in my conceptual understanding of the question

I agree with both your answers : to part (a) it makes sense: as any point on that line should remain invariant under the transformation. So must be a linear transformation with an eigenvalue of 1, and the eigenspace indeed is the line.
The same logic applies for (b): Any point which lies on the line does not change position under the transformation, so should remain invariant under the transformation. So an eigenvalue would be 1, and the associated eigenspace is the line on which the points remain invariant. However, I don't think necessarily they all have to be 1.
For example let:
$
  T(v) =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
    1 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \\
    0 & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
  \end{array} } \right]\mathbf{v}
$
which is a rotation of 45 degrees counterclockwise about the x axis. This has an eigenvalue of 1, and then two complex eigenvalues. So not all of them are 1.
Edit: Further to this, a thought just occurred to me. Another eigenvalue for the first reflection matrix will be -1. This will refer to the eigenspace of the reflection along the perpendicular to the line of reflection at zero. In situation 2: We may have -1 as an eigenvalue if the rotation is 180 degrees about the axis , for a similar reason to the 2D case , so we don't even necessarily have all the eigenvalues being complex.

Your edit is exactly right: the reflection in $\Bbb{R}^2$ and the rotation through $180^{\circ}$ in $\Bbb{R}^3$ have real eigenvalues.

@RobArthan My reasoning for the case in 3D was along the lines that for there to be another real eigenvalue , you would have to have the origin , the original point, and the reflected point being collinear , which is only possible if you do 180 degrees . Though now I say it , there's another (trivial) case, for a rotation of 360 degrees, there is also a triple repeated eigenvalue of 1 as well (everything maps to itself)
